# Can I still take the knowledge test with the US government shutdown?

Tags: faa-knowledge-test

Non-Essential employees at the FAA are out of work due to the US Government shutdown.  I am nearing the end of my Private Pilot Training and am almost ready to take the Knowledge test.  With the US Government shutdown, can I still take the knowledge test or do I have to wait for the government to reopen?

Comment: Is it administered via an automated online system these days? When I did mine back in the '90s, it was on paper in the FBO's office and mailed in for grading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like private testing centers can conduct the tests now.

Full details here, from 22 Sept 2017.

https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8080.6H.pdf